# Proving a hyperbolic identity.

Tags: trigonometry

I have worked from LHS to RHS, and it is simple. Now from LHS there is a challenge, starting definition of $\sinh(x)$, how can we ensure a double angle identity is used; here is the question.I just need a starting idea.
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{2\tanh(x/2)}{1-\tanh^2(x/2)}$$

Comment: $\sinh(x)=\frac{(e^{x/2})^2-(e^{-x/2})^2}{2}$ and $\tanh(x/2)=\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}$. When you replace those in both sides you get sums and products and quotients of $e^{x/2}$. Simplify those.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers that have been posted, Waitara?

Comment: Oh Yes these are great methods I must say! Now am only concerned with the word"replace" ;could this not negate the spirit of proof? I am using your answer from sinh (x) to get to tanh(x/2) using these exponential definitions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "negate the spirit of proof". Anyway, if one of the answers is satisfactory for you, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sinh x=2\sinh(x/2)\cosh(x/2)={2\sinh(x/2)\over{\rm sech}(x/2)}={2\sinh(x/2)/\cosh(x/2)\over{\rm sech}^2(x/2)}={2\tanh(x/2)\over1-\tanh^2(x/2)}$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$ to show that
$$1-\tanh^2(t)=\frac{1}{\cosh^2(t)}$$
Then take $t=x/2$. Note that $\sinh(2t)=2\sinh(t)\cosh(t)$, similarly to the sine function.